# How to do a 3 level drill down with Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, drilldown, donut-chart

I'm currently playing around with this example, and I don't understand how to make a 3 level drilldown for this.

```
        name = 'Browser brands',
        data = [{
                y: 55.11,
                color: colors[0],
                drilldown: {
                    name: 'MSIE versions',
                    categories: ['MSIE 6.0', 'MSIE 7.0', 'MSIE 8.0', 'MSIE 9.0'],
                    data: [10.85, 7.35, 33.06, 2.81],
                    color: colors[0]
                }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-donut/

There's currently 2 categories of data there, for example, browser, browser version and I want to make another category, works with CSS3 or doesn't work with CSS3 which will be a boolean value.

Comment: But you want drilldown (like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6LXVQ/1/ ) or just another ring in a pie chart?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another `series`.
E.g.

```
{
        name: 'CSS 3',
        data: cssData,
        size: '100%',
        innerSize: '70%',
        dataLabels: {
            formatter: function () {
                // display only if larger than 1
                return this.y > 1 ? '<b>' + this.point.name + ':</b> ' + this.y + '%' : null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Also you need to modify the `size` and `innerSize` of the other series' to match, aswell as add specific data as a `drilldown` if you wanted to make it accurate.  For the sake of simplicity, I've just added a simple yes/no series data here but you would need to make another `drilldown` for each browser version and then parse that as the others are to make `cssData`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/zRgLp/1/